# roleAssignment & diagnosticLog deployments fail if role/log already exist

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-bicep

I'm using bicep to assign roles to my resources - the first run works perfectly, but any consecutive run fails because the role already exists. The same goes for diagnosticLogs - if they already exist, the pipeline fails.

Is there any way to check if the resource exist and skip the resource-deployment if so? Or at the very least to reduce the severity to a "warning", so the pipeline doesn't fail?

It took me a while to figure out the problem, because the log of Azure Pipelines does not even return an error description, but just fails...

```
##[error]At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.
##[error]Details:
##[error]DeploymentFailed: At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.
##[error]Check out the troubleshooting guide to see if your issue is addressed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting
##[error]Task failed while creating or updating the template deployment.
```

Here is the log from the resource-group deployments - diagnosticLogs:

```
{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. 
Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details":[{
"code":"Conflict",
"message":"Data sink '/subscriptions/X-X-X-X-X/resourceGroups/<NAME>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<NAME>' 
is already used in diagnostic setting '<NAME>' for category 'allLogs'. 
Data sinks can't be reused in different settings on the same category for the same resource."
}]}
```

The error from the roleAssignment:

```
{"code":"DeploymentFailed",
"message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details":[{
"code":"RoleAssignmentExists",
"message":"The role assignment already exists."
}]}
```

Here is the bicep code for the deployment:

```
// roleAssignment
resource role_developer_adls_blob_contributors 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2022-04-01' = {
  name: guid(resourceGroup().id, aad_admin_developer_group_object_id)
  scope: resourceGroup()
  properties:{
    description: 'Developer Group - BlobStorageContributor.'
    principalId: aad_admin_developer_group_object_id
    principalType: 'Group'
    roleDefinitionId: resourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', storageBlobDataContributorRoleID)
  }
}


// diagnosticLogs
resource keyvault_diagnostic_settings 'Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings@2021-05-01-preview' = {
  name: '${keyVaultName}-log-adls'
  scope: key_vault
  properties: {
    storageAccountId: adls_storage_base.id
    logs: [
      {
        categoryGroup: 'allLogs'
        enabled : true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: could you paste the fulle error message please ? if you go to the azure portal, dpeloyment tab on the resource you would be able to see the full logs

Comment: That's already the full error message... I added the last two lines of the error message, but they do not add any value or information but merely reference the link.

Comment: have you checked error on azure portal ? in the deployments of the resource group ?

Comment: Ah, good point - I added it to the question.

Comment: are you doing multiple role assignment in other part of your template for the same group ? For diagnostic log, do you have other logs configured as well ? Or did you changed the log name ?

Comment: only one diagnosticLog per resource, the same log name as before.  The roleAssignment is also unchanged. I basically run the deployment twice - first on a clean slate and everything works, the second run without any changes to the configuration and it throws the above errors.

Comment: for the role assignment. according to the error message, otherwise this is not unique `guid(resourceGroup().id, aad_admin_developer_group_object_id)` or there is already a role assignment for the same group and same role at the same scope.

Comment: Yes,  there "is already a role assignment for the same group and same role at the same scope" - from the first run of the deployment. The point is that I want to be able to run the entire deployment again every night to make sure all resources exist + have the correct config. But the second and any subsequent deployment run fails because it already exists. That is the whole problem.

Comment: Hence my question of "Is there any way to check if the resource exist and skip the resource-deployment if so?"

Comment: if the name is the same it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The roleAssignment `name` needs to be unique for a given principal, role and scope.  The seed you have for the `guid()` function is not unique enough.  It should be:

```
name: guid(resourceGroup().id, aad_admin_developer_group_object_id, storageBlobDataContributorRoleID)
```

Note that since you already have a roleAssigment for the principal with those perms at that scope, you'll have to remove the "old" roleAssignment before you can use the new naming scheme.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that there is no way in bicep to check whether a role assignment is already active and if so to skip that part of the deployment? I'd rather not have to remove all role assignments before re-deploying via bicep... :(

Comment: Yes and no... it's not that the roleAssignment exists (which makes it "active"), it's that a roleAssignment with a given set of properties for principalId, roleDefinitionId and scope already exists with a different name *or* the roleAssignment exists with a given name and a different set of poperties than you're requesting.  roleAssignments are unique resources in this respect -- that the properties become immutable for a given name.  If you don't use a standard naming practice then you need to use one that's sufficiently unique and idempotent.  The simplest way may be a clean slate.

Comment: There is a third option - that a given name with the **same** set of properties already exists. This is the case for me.

Comment: Yep - the key in this case is that if you want to declare that role in a template, then it's often easiest to remove that "old" role so you can follow a consistent pattern in naming them across the tenant.